# How to insert and retrive records into Database in moodle

Tags: moodle

Hai i want to insert my form fields into database and retrive records from database in moodle. how to do that :

Here is my form what i created :

Uplo.php

```
<?php


 require_once('config.php');
 require_once("$CFG->libdir/formslib.php");

class uplo extends moodleform {

public function definition() {
    global $CFG;

    $mform = $this->_form;



    $buttonarray=array();

    $mform->addElement('text', 'name', get_string('name')); 
    $mform->setType('name', PARAM_NOTAGS);                   
    $mform->setDefault('name', 'Please enter name');  

    $mform->addElement('text', 'email', get_string('email')); 
    $mform->setType('email', PARAM_NOTAGS);                   
    $mform->setDefault('email', 'Please enter email');  


    $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('submit', 'submitbutton',  get_string('savechanges'));
    $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('cancel');
    $mform->addGroup($buttonarray, 'buttonar', '', array(' '), false);
    $mform->closeHeaderBefore('buttonar');

}

function validation($data, $files) {
    return array();
 }
}

 ?>
```

Testing.php:

```
<?php
 define('_DB_HOST_NAME','localhost');
 define('_DB_USER_NAME','root');
 define('_DB_PASSWORD','');
 define('_DB_DATABASE_NAME','moodle_test');

 $dbConnection = mysqli_connect(_DB_HOST_NAME,_DB_USER_NAME,_DB_PASSWORD,_DB_DATABASE_NAME);
?>

<?php

 require_once('uplo.php');


 $mform = new uplo();

 $mform->display();

 if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){

  $name = $mform->get_data('name');
  $email = $mform->get_data('email');

  $table='insert';

  $res=insert_record($table, $name,$email, $returnid=true, $primarykey='id') ;

  }



?>
```

This one is i tried. how to do that in a right way

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'/../../config.php') (adjust the number of '/../' based on the subdirectory your file is in, relative to config.php).

The use the Moodle data manipulation API https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

Comment: i am using version 1.9.2 is it possible to use $DB global variable in my version

Comment: No, you need to use the older API, without the $DB global, for Moodle 1.9. However, support for Moodle 1.9 was dropped several years ago, so your primary concern should be upgrading to a supported version of Moodle (or at the very least Moodle 1.9.17, the last released Moodle 1.9). There are known security problems with the version you are using.

Comment: i am using another version 1.9.19+ is it possible to use $DB. and how to insert data into database using 1.9.19+

Comment: No, the database commands are named similarly in Moodle 1.9, but without $DB. e.g. get_record, update_record, etc

Comment: i am trying insert_record() function but it is not working correctly what's wrong in my above coding